# C# ForEach Loop (string declaration in loop)

Tags: c#, foreach

I have this string array of names.

```
string[] someArray = { "Messi", "Ronaldo", "Bale", "Neymar", "Pele" };

foreach (string item in someArray)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(item);
  }
```

When I run in debug mode with breakpoint on foreach line, and using Step Into, string item is highlighted each time with each pass like it declares it again. I suppose it should highlight item only. Does this mean that with each time item is declared again?

Note: using VS 2012.

Comment: What would be your concern if it was?

Comment: I do not have any concern, just trying to understand what's going on. I am new in coding. If I understand code better, it gives me some confidence I can get it :)

Comment: Also, from what I was learning till now, variable is declared only once. However, this maybe be break of that rule (.net runtime gets rid of it)? Not a big deal, just trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer here is subtle because the question is (accidentally) unclear.  Let me clarify it by breaking it apart into multiple questions.

> Is the loop variable logically redeclared every time I go through a `foreach` loop?

As the other answer correctly notes, in C# 5 and higher, yes. In C# 1 through 4, no.

> What is the observable consequence of that change?

In C# 1 there is no way to tell the difference. (And the spec is actually unclear as to where the variable is declared.)

In C# 2 the team added closures in the form of anonymous methods. If there are multiple closures that capture a loop variable in C# 2, 3 and 4 they all capture the same variable, and they all see it mutate as the loop runs. This is almost never what you want.

In C# 5 we took the breaking change to say that a new loop variable is declared every time through the loop, and so each closure captures a different variable and therefore does not observe it changing.

> Why does the debugger go back to the loop variable declaration every time I step through the loop?

To inform you that the loop variable is being mutated. If you have

```
IEnumerable<string> someCollection = whatever;
foreach(string item in someCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

That is logically equivalent to

```
IEnumerable<string> someCollection = whatever;
{
    IEnumerator<string> enumerator = someCollection.GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        while( enumerator.MoveNext() )
        {
            string item;  // In C# 4.0 and before, this is outside the while
            item = enumerator.Current;
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (enumerator != null)
            ((IDisposable)enumerator).Dispose();
    }
}
```

If you were debugging around that expanded version of the code, you would see the debugger highlight the invocations of `MoveNext` and `Current`. Well, the debugger does the same thing in the compact form; when `MoveNext` is about to be called the debugger highlights the `in`, for lack of anything better to highlight. When `Current` is about to be called it highlights `item`. Again, what would be the better thing to highlight?

> So the fact that the debugger highlights the variable has nothing to do with whether the variable is redeclared?

Correct. It highlights the variable when `Current` is about to be called, because that will mutate the variable. It mutates the variable regardless of whether it is a new variable, in C# 5, or the same variable as before, in C# 4.

> I noticed that you changed my example to use a generic sequence rather than an array. Why did you do that?

Because if the C# compiler knows that the collection in the `foreach` is an array, it actually just generates a good old fashioned `for` loop rather than calling `MoveNext` and `Current` and all that. Doing so is typically faster and produces less collection pressure, so it's a win all around.

However, the C# team wants the debugging experience to feel the same regardless. So again, the code generator creates stepping points on `in` -- this time where the generated `for`'s loop variable is mutated -- and again, on the code which mutates the `foreach` loop variable. That way the debugging experience is consistent.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. This clears it a lot. I have only 1 month xp in programming, advanced topic for me.

Comment: @ExpertLoser: This is indeed a pretty advanced topic for a beginner. Your curiosity about figuring out how things work will be a great asset I'm sure! I am at present writing a series of videos for beginner C# programmers; if you have any insights as to what concepts are difficult for beginners, feel free to drop me a note at eric@lippert.com.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on which version of C# you are targeting. In C# 5, it's a new variable.  Before that, the variable was reused.

See Eric Lippert's blog post here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

From the post:

> UPDATE: We are taking the breaking change. In C# 5, the loop variable
>   of a foreach will be logically inside the loop, and therefore closures
>   will close over a fresh copy of the variable each time. The "for" loop
>   will not be changed. We return you now to our original article.

Comment: Ok, so with each pass new variable declaration as I understand it?